# Get keys with their values from object store with YDN-DB

Tags: javascript, database, indexeddb, ydn-db, persistent-object-store

I know how to get object values with [YDN-DB](https://dev.yathit.com/ydn-db/index.html) from an object store but is it also possible to get these values together with their primary keys?

Answer (score 0):

Common ydn-db query method does not return both keys and values. You have to use either `scan` or `open` methods, which operates on cursors.

Base on the [db.open API example](http://dev.yathit.com/api/ydn/db/storage.html#open):

```
var iter = ydn.db.ValueIterator.where('player', 'clad', '=', 'hobbit');
var req = db.open(function(icursor) {
  var player = icursor.getValue();
  var key = icursor.getKey(); // this must be 'hobbit'
  var primary = icursor.getPrimaryKey(); 
  ...
```

See [icursor](http://dev.yathit.com/api/ydn/db/icursor.html) API for detail.

Comment: Kyaw Tun, could you provide mini example, I can't understand ydn-db Qoery wiki about open method, i tried serverl times but not worked for me

Comment: @Kyaw Tun,I'm using autoincrement and the id is sent with all records using the .values() function